# haskell arrows confusion when trying to use proc and do notation

Tags: haskell, arrows

I have been trying to write a more compact version of some Haskell code that uses arrows.

I am trying to convert the xml to a list of tuples.

Running tx2 produces:
[("Item 1","Item One",["p1_1","p1_2","p1_3"]),("Item 2","Item Two",["p2_1","p2_2"])]

The code that I have works but I cannot help thinking that I should not have to use as many runLA calls as I do.  I call runLA for each of **getDesc**, **getDisp**, and **getPlist**.

I thought I might be able to use **proc** and **do** notation to simplify

```
{-# LANGUAGE Arrows, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
module Test1 where

import Text.XML.HXT.Arrow.ReadDocument
import Text.XML.HXT.Core

xml = "<top>\
               \<list>\
            \<item>\
                \<desc>Item 1</desc>\
                \<plist>\
                    \<p>p1_1</p>\
                    \<p>p1_2</p>\
                    \<p>p1_3</p>\
                \</plist>\
                \<display>Item One</display>\
            \</item>\
            \<item>\
                \<desc>Item 2</desc>\
                \<plist>\
                    \<p>p2_1</p>\
                    \<p>p2_2</p>\
                \</plist>\
                \<display>Item Two</display>\
            \</item>\
        \</list>\
    \</top>"

tx1 = runLA (xread >>> getChildren >>> hasName "list" >>> getChildren >>> hasName "item") xml
tx2 = map toTuple tx1

toTuple i = let
            desc = getDesc i
            display = getDisp i
            plist = getPlist i
            in (desc, display, plist)

aDesc = getChildren >>> hasName "desc" >>> getChildren >>> getText >>> unlistA
aDisp = getChildren >>> hasName "display" >>> getChildren >>> getText >>> unlistA
aPlist = getChildren >>> hasName "plist" >>> getChildren >>> deep getText

getDesc i = runLA aDesc i
getDisp i = runLA aDisp i
getPlist i = runLA aPlist i
```

But when I try to rewrite tx2 as follows:

```
aToTuple = proc tree -> do
                desc    <-  aDesc  -< tree
            display <-  aDisp -< tree
            plist   <- aPlist -< tree
            returnA -< (desc, display, plist)

tx3 = map (\i -> runLA aToTuple i) tx1
```

It all falls in a big heap.

What am I missing with the conversion to proc/do notation?

Thanks.

Comment: are you using `-XArrows`?

Comment: @AndrewJaffe: There's a pragma at the top of the code sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost never have to call a `run`-function several times on HXT
arrow to get the result you want. In your case, [`listA`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowList.html#v%3alistA) can be used instead of
`map runLA` to get a list of results from an arrow. You can also get rid of
many of the `getChildren` calls by using the [`/>`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/hxt/latest/doc/html/Control-Arrow-ArrowTree.html#v%3a-47--62-) operator.

Your `proc`-version of `toTuple` looks fine to me, but I'd rewrite the rest of
your example code as

```
tx1 = runLA (xread /> hasName "list" /> hasName "item" >>> toTuple) xml

toTuple = proc tree -> do
    desc <- aDesc -< tree
    disp <- aDisp -< tree
    plist <- aPlist -< tree
    returnA -< (desc, disp, plist)


aDesc  = getChildren >>> hasName "desc" /> getText
aDisp  = getChildren >>> hasName "display" /> getText
aPlist = getChildren >>> hasName "plist" >>> listA (getChildren /> getText)
```

And instead of using arrow notation, `toTuple` can be written simply as

```
toTuple = aDesc &&& aDisp &&& aPlist >>> arr3 (,,)
```

Comment: Thanks very much, that does exactly what I wanted, now to understand what it is doing.  Thanks again